# Copy a Record in bindingsource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want learn some C#. So  Icreated a Winforms. I connected the Form to a SQL-Server 2008 by using a Dataset.
The Form has also a TableAdapter, a TableAdapter, a Bindingnavigator and a Bindingsource.
The Forms has some Textboxes on it.

The Form gets the Data by:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                                          
        this._CranesTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1._Cranes); 
    }
```

I assume that the Tableadapter fills the Table _Cranes in the Dataset with Records.
I also have some code to add a new record.

```
  this._CranesBindingSource.AddNew();
  this._CranesBindingSource.MoveLast();
```

That is working very well.
But now I want to copy the record which is in focus.

Can someone help me? I hope my informations are enough.

Comment: Whereto do you want to copy?

Comment: In the same bindingsource. I want to copy the record, besides the id. The id should be a other. Then go to the record and change some fields and save the data.

Answer (score 2):

A `BindingSource` [Encapsulates the data source for a form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); it doesn't store any data. All data are stored in a `DataTable` or a `DataSet`, which, for work with DataBases, contains `DataTable`(s) collection called `Tables`; The `DataTable` finally holds the actual data in `DataRows`.

One of the thing a `BindingSource` does for you is to keep track of the current row and to offer a mechanism to move forward and backward through the rows.

(Note `DataBinding` is not only for DataBase data but for all sorts of data containers in .Net!)

So if you want to copy the current row you can do it by

- getting a handle to the current row
- getting a handle to the table
- importing the row into the table

With your `CranesBindingSource` this would be the code:

```
DataRow cRow = (DataRow)CranesBindingSource.Current;
DataTable dt = (DataTable)CranesBindingSource.DataSource;
dt.ImportRow(cRow);
```

This piece of code assumes that the `DataSource` is a `DataTable`. If instead it is  a `DataSet` it contains a table collection `Tables` and you would have to use to respective table or index into the collection like so:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)CranesBindingSource.DataSet.Tables[0];
```

After that it is up to you to change the data, especially the key as you like or need.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
I tried this code but there is an error.
"The Object from type System.Data.DataRowView can not be converted into the type System.Data.DataRow"

Comment: Do you get the error for the 1st line? You could try: `DataRow cRow = ((DataRowView)CranesBindingSource.Current).Row;`